# Problems using the ? wildcard for a MySQL stored procedure when updating from Java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have the following Java class that accepts 11 parameters and uses them to create a new record in a database. The stored procedure is tested and works in MySQL, but I can't get the Java class accessing it to work:

```
public void insert_saved_pub_set(int user_id, String presProfile, String procProfile, String dateLabel, String doc_id, String pubName, String lastLoaded, String publicV, String label, String description, String out_id)
                throws SQLException {                   

    String sql = "call insert_saved_pub_set(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    stmt.setInt(1, user_id);        
    stmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(presProfile));
    stmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(procProfile));
    stmt.setString(4, dateLabel);
    stmt.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(doc_id));
    stmt.setString(6, pubName);
    stmt.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(lastLoaded));
    stmt.setInt(8, Integer.parseInt(publicV));
    stmt.setString(9, label);
    stmt.setString(10, description);
    stmt.setInt(11, Integer.parseInt(out_id));

    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

}
```

The error I get when I attempt to test this is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1

I've tested the prepared statement from Java with hardcoded values and it works, but I've doing something stupid with the wildcards and I've stared at it too long.

** comment added post-fix below **

Just to close this off, the fixed code looks like this:

```
public void insert_saved_pub_set(int user_id, String presProfile, String procProfile, String dateLabel, String doc_id, String pubName, String lastLoaded, String publicV, String label, String description, String out_id)
            throws SQLException {               

        String sql = "call insert_saved_pub_set(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";       

        CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);        

        cStmt.setInt(1, user_id);       
        cStmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(presProfile));
        cStmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(procProfile));
        cStmt.setString(4, dateLabel);
        cStmt.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(doc_id));
        cStmt.setString(6, pubName);
        cStmt.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(lastLoaded));
        cStmt.setInt(8, Integer.parseInt(publicV));
        cStmt.setString(9, label);
        cStmt.setString(10, description);   
        cStmt.setInt(11, Integer.parseInt(out_id)); 

        cStmt.executeUpdate();
        }       

    }
```

Comment: its not java code what you put inside the `String sql`, you have errors but not because of the `?` in java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `executeUpdate(String)` method is inherited from `Statement` and attempts to execute the given SQL statement as is -- without placeholder substitution.

The [`executeUpdate()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--) (no parameters), declared in `PreparedStatement`, will perform placeholder substitution.  This works with `PreparedStatements` such as update statements.

In addition, you aren't running a straight SQL statement here.  You are calling a stored procedure.  Switch from `PreparedStatement` to [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).

```
CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
```

The "set" methods work as before, but then you call `execute()` to execute the `CallableStatement`.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I'd asked a couple hours ago. Of course, if I'd done that, I would have this swell headache.

Answer (score 2):

To call a stored procedure, you need a [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), not a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Quoting `CallableStatement` Javadoc:

> The interface used to execute SQL stored procedures.

This is a sample code to get you started:

```
CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call insert_saved_pub_set(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
cStmt.setInt(1, user_id);
// ... rest of code

boolean hadResults = cStmt.execute(); // executes the stored procedure
while (hadResults) {
    ResultSet rs = cStmt.getResultSet();

    // process result set
    ...

    hadResults = cStmt.getMoreResults();
}
```

I suggest you read [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html) about the usage of stored procedure in Java code.